# Cannot get cookie data in Vue.js and Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cookies

I am building an api for application in Laravel 6 lets say it sits at `example.com/api` and SPA front end built in vue lets say that sits at `example.com`. My API sets a cookie when a user is authenticated I am wanting to access that cookie in my vue.js application, I have installed [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) I can see the cookie exists in dev-tools, but when I run `$cookies.get('cookie_name')` it returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I create my cookie in the API,

```php
$payload = [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->id
    ];

    Session::put('user', $payload);
    Session::save();
    $session_id = Session::getId();

    $cookie = cookie('cookie_name', $session_id);
```

Comment: Routes in the API file on Laravel are stateless (as most APIs are) and so do not pass cookies back on responses.

Comment: Can you show the way you've configured `vue-cookies`? It should be `this.$cookies.get('cookie_name')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Laravel does not have the middleware required for cookies on any api route.

Usually APIs are stateless and therefore do not use cookies.

You can however, enable this functionality by adding the middleware `\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class` to the api group in `Http\Kernel.php`

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\NoSuperUserOnFrontEnd::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class, <- add this

    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks - in that case there may be better way of structuring the project that I am not aware off. I am wanting to create an SPA front end, that can interact with cookies, and backend service, not necesarily an API in it's truest sense. Is there a better way than I am currently doing. Which is basically a catch all route in web.php for the front to serve the SPA

Comment: That's an entirely new question, please mark this as answered, if you believe it to be.